# How to draw a strip under the TOC title

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, diagrams

I would like to put a strip under the title of the TOC, as in the below picture.

I haven't found any example googling.
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[pagesize,12pt,bibtotoc,pointlessnumbers,
normalheadings, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[twoside=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc, color}
\geometry{
    papersize={397.85pt,597.27pt},
    top=66.28pt, %3cm, % Top margin
    bottom=53.61pt, %3cm, % Bottom margin
    left=43pt, %3cm, % Left margin
    right=43pt, %3cm, % Right margin
    headheight=12pt, % Header height
    textheight=465pt,
    textwidth=306pt,
    footskip=42pt, % 1.4cm, % Space from the bottom margin to the baseline of the footer
    headsep=20pt % Space from the top margin to the baseline of the header
}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents itself
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\lipsum[3-4]
\chapter{Chapter 3}
\lipsum[4-5]
\chapter{Chapter 4}
\lipsum[6-7]
\chapter{Chapter 5}
\lipsum[8-9]
\chapter{Chapter 6}
\lipsum[10-11]
\chapter{Chapter 7}
\lipsum[12-13]
\chapter{Chapter 8}
\lipsum[14-15]
\chapter{Chapter 9}
\lipsum[16-17]
\chapter{Chapter 10}
\lipsum[18-19]
\end{document}
```

That's what I would like to get:

[image]

Comment: Ah, you probably mean some african decorative pattern of stripes, like those: https://www.amazon.com/Geometric-Traditional-Waterproof-Polyester-Decorations/dp/B08B85YYFZ . Perhaps there are some fonts or images that can be used here? // Kewwe Boho can be a keyword to search for. // Also, have a look here: https://ctan.org/topic/decoration

Comment: See decorules there. // Also check for glyphs . May be similar exist and you can typeset them as ordinary text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package pgfornament provides many interesting ornaments.  Let us use ornament number 7 from this package.

We need to create decorative line of ornaments.  We define ornament box

```
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\newbox\orn
\setbox\orn=\hbox to 10.05pt{\pgfornament[width=10.05pt]{7}}
```

(The length 10.05pt was chosen after some trial and errors).

The command `\noindent\leavevmode\leaders\copy\orn\hfill\kern0pt\par` fills a line with this ornament.  Let us add this (and a thick rule) to the `\tableofcontents` command:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
          \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
      \vspace*{-2.5\baselineskip}% 
      \rule{\textwidth}{3pt}\par
      \vspace*{-.5\baselineskip}%
      \noindent\leavevmode\leaders\copy\orn\hfill\kern0pt\par
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\makeatother
```

[image]

P.S. @nino_user183677 explained they have a graphics file with the ornament.  This makes it even simpler:  we just need to redefine `\tableofcontents`.  Assuming that the filename is `myornament.png` or `myornament.pdf`, or `myornament.jpg`,

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
          \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
      \vspace*{-2.5\baselineskip}% 
      \rule{\textwidth}{3pt}\par
      \vspace*{-.5\baselineskip}%
      \noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth}{myornament}\par
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\makeatother
```

Comment: Hi @Boris Thank you. It works well, but how can I use my own decoration?

Comment: Do you have this decoration in any format?  What is the format?

Comment: Yes. I have the decoration in the following formats: ps, png and jpg

Comment: (Boris, I don't understand wuy the markdown with _Boris_ doesn't work!) your modified code doesn't work. I get the message "Missing \begin{document}..., but I've found a similar solution using the package [https://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos][textpos] and the command _\textblock_. Thank you very much.